# The export/import issue in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm learning TypeScript and want to use export/import mechanism. I have 3 .ts files and the code looks as following:

1) MyClass.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/dx.all.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../Scripts/go.d.ts" />

export class MyClass {
    render(divId: string, text: string): void {
        ...
    }
    getData(): void {
        ...
    }
}
```

2) Caller.ts:

```
import { MyClass } from './MyClass';

export class Caller {
    execute() {
        let myClass: MyClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.render("content", "Hello World");
        myClass.getData();
    }
}
```

3) Main.ts:

```
import { Caller } from './Caller';

window.onload = () => {
    let caller: Caller = new Caller();
    caller.execute();
};
```

4) HTML:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/MyClass.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/Caller.js"></script>>
<script src="~/Scripts/Main.js"></script>
```

But, nothing is displayed.

There are 3 errors:

- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export (for MyClass.js)
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import (for Caller.js)
- Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import (for Main.js)

Comment: you should look into a module loader, like SystemJs to load your files. Or at least check the outputed js files and see what's in there, it might give you a clue on how to proceed.

Comment: from angular i know you have to put file in module and than you can load that module..........

Comment: Paste `MyClass` render and getData functions body, cause we don't even know where the code is failing. Is it Main, Caller or MyClass code.

Comment: I've updated my post by adding errors I've got.

Comment: I've added: "module": "commonjs" to tsconfig.json file, but it didn't help.

Comment: Looks to me like your TS compiler is not setup properly. Which version of EcmaScript are you compiling to? `import` and `export` were added in ES6.

Comment: Can you show us compiled JS files.

Comment: Usually when working with TypeScript you also set up compilation step to output the code into one bundled file, then there is no need for imports and exports - they are useful for the development, but not used often in production.

Comment: I've found workaround by removing export and import directives and adding triple-slash directives instead of import. Everything works fine.

Comment: I've set up" "target" to "es6" in my tsconfig.json file.

Comment: And I've added: "module": "commonjs".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing the `<script>`, I guess it's in a web application. And the files are using ES6 modules syntax.

Currently, I think that only Google Chrome supports natively ES6 modules. No other browser support any kind of module (ES6, CommonJS, AMD, SystemJs, UMD, ...). If the app is meant to be executed only in Chrome, you can set the tsconfig option `module='ES6'`.

Else, use either:

- [TypeScript namespaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) instead of [modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

  - *recommended for a small project and/or short life cycle*
- a module loader like [SystemJs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) to load your main script and its dependancies

  - *a bit more complicated*
  - *implies more HTTP requests to load the HTML page*
- a module bundler like [WebPack](https://webpack.js.org/) or the new in the place [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) to compile in advance your ES6 modules into plain javascript file(s) understandable by any browser

  - *the more complicated solution*
  - *see this [tutorial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html) for help*

Comment: Thank you for suggestions. I've just tried to use Rollup, but I'm not sure what to expect because I've never used such a tools before. Should I get 1 bundle .js file that I can use instead of 3 I have?

Comment: I've used this command: rollup Main.js -o bundle.js -f cjs and bundle.js file has been created. But, it contains only content of Main.js file and there is no content of files that should be imported.

Comment: Prefer option `--f iife` instead of `umd` unless using also SystemJs. Also, use TypeScript compile option `module: "ES6"`, because it's the module format that Rollup understands natively.